# How to change CMYK of current active document with respect to Highlight, Midtone and Shadow using Adobe Illustrator Scripting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I want to create a plugin for abode illustrator using extendScript to change CMYK as per Highlight, Midtone, and Shadow.

I have tried to change CMYK but was not able to change with respect to Highlight, Midtone and Shadow.

I have tried to do in this way by fetching the pixels of active document to change their CMYK but only able to get coordinates in points (Not in Pixels) of the selected path items/object.

```
    // Added a click event on a button to get the color code of selected pathItem 
    $("#get-pixel").click(function() {
        csInterface.evalScript('getPixelColorCode()');
    });


    // to print the selected object coordinates in alert box (.jsx file)
    function getPixelColorCode() {
        var selectedItem = app.activeDocument.selection; 
        alert(selectedItem);
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedItem.length; i++) {
            if (selectedItem[i].typename == "PathItem") {
                var pos = selectedItem[i].position;
                alert(pos[0]+ ", "+pos[1]+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you have pixels in a pathItem? Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53856449/edit) to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad,  I tried to get all the pixels of the selected pathItem, but the position returns [x,y] in points not in pixels

Comment: That's the point: PathItems don't have pixels. I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I want to change the CMYK color as it does in Photoshop by using Curves feature. Is there any way to achieve this feature for Adobe Illustrator? Can you point me out in the document if there is any way?

Comment: You may want to look at the colour editing tools (`Edit -> Edit Colors`). Can you do what you want to script manually? That's usually a good place to start in order to figure out what your script has to do.